# Average True Range - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I copied the below formula from Google Doc help forums, on how to caculate ATR using Google sheets. The formula works for number of days below 20, for days above 20 it returns the below error:

> Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 22. Actual: 21.

Could you please help me by fixing the error.
Trading has drawn me into google sheets & excel, and at the moment the below is beyond my skills, I'm still working with IF statements.

Link to the forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/gENldwEI040;context-place=forum/docs

$B1 - ticker Cell

40 - Period (days)

```
=average(ARRAYFORMULA(query(query(transpose(abs(query({query({Googlefinance($B1,"High",today(),today()-(40)),Googlefinance($B1,"low",today(),today()-(40+6))},"select Col1,Col2,Col4 order by Col1 desc limit "&40&" "),query(Googlefinance($B1,"close",today(),today()- (40+6)),"select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit "&40&" offset 1 label Col2 'closeyest' ")}, "select Col2-Col3, Col2-Col4, Col3-Col4"))), "select max(Col"&join(",max(Col",row(indirect("A1:A"&40))&")")))))
```

Comment: Adding file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8zVBqdwTZ_dt-Vc_3olkopnfG9lEYUCd5oqyxvHyn8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you figured this out? It seems it only gives this error because of the time taken to retrieve the results.

Comment: Hi, No I hadn't figured it out. The idea was to find a way to normalise the ATR. Decided to use ATR(14)/100

Answer (score 2):

This is working

```
=average(ARRAYFORMULA(query(query(transpose(abs(query({query({Googlefinance($B1,"High",today()-(100),today()),
Googlefinance($B1,"low",today()-(100),today())},
"select Col1,Col2,Col4 order by Col1 desc limit "&40&" "), query(Googlefinance($B1,"close",today()-(100),today()),
"select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit "&40&" offset 1 label Col2 'closeyest' ")}, 
"select Col2-Col3, Col2-Col4, Col3-Col4"))), 
"select max(Col"&join(",
max(Col",row(indirect("A1:A"&40))&")")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined both the formulas as named functions in google sheets, then use an if function to pickup any of the two formulas to compute ATR.

The benefit of this approach is that when you input the number of days along with the ticker symbol you tend to get more accurate value of ATR, beyond 30 days the second formula takes over and applies 40 days fixed value for lookback.